# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/ClassLoaderAccess;)V

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a project that uses hibernate. I am getting following exception when I run the code. Specifically while building session factory:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/ClassLoaderAccess;)V
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(JPAMetadataProvider.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(JPAMetadataProvider.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl.generateHcannReflectionManager(BootstrapContextImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl.<init>(BootstrapContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:653)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
```

Following is sessionFactory build code:

```
sessionFactory =
      new Configuration()
      .configure("hibernate.config.xml")
      .buildSessionFactory();
```

I have following hibernate dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.22.redhat-2:provided
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.31.Final-redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.5.Final-redhat-00002:provided

I understand that it is not able to find the constructor for XMLContext when it is invoked in JPAMetadataProvider.java but not sure why it is not finding it since the project has all the required dependencies included. To summarizeon the required dependecies here are those:

org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA
org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.31.Final-redhat-00001:compile
org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.5.Final-redhat-00002:provided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hibernate-annotations module is no longer needed (merged into core) since Hibernate 3.6. So you should remove it else there will be conflicts in classes.

see https://in.relation.to/2012/04/05/no-more-hibernateannotations-module/ which explains the rationale.